# PHP/MySQL - Next occurrence of 4am

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to create a statement either in MySQL or PHP, that will only select values that occur before the next occurrence of 4am ie the next time 4am occurs. I currently have a SELECT statement like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `dated` 
WHERE (
  DATE(`start_timestamp`) = DATE(NOW())
  OR DATE(`end_timestamp`) = DATE(NOW())
)
```

Which gets me those available today, however, I would like to exclude results that have a date of today but occur after 4am

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
select *
from dated
where start_timestamp <= date(now() - interval 4 hour) + interval 28 hour;
```

This subtract four hours from the current time and uses `date()` to truncate the time portion.  It then adds back one day and four hours to get the next 4:00 a.m.

EDIT:

To filter from the last 4 a.m. to the next one uses the same idea:

```
select *
from dated
where start_timestamp >= date(now() - interval 4 hour) + interval 4 hour and
      start_timestamp < date(now() - interval 4 hour) + interval 28 hour;
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this work so that it filters anything from the previous 4am to the next 4am?